# Identifying the parameter that flips the solution

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-value, stochastic-calculus, system-variables

I have solved a system of ODEs numerically. As the plot shows, the solution `SolJx` is positive for the parameters I have chosen. However, if you decrease (more negative) the value of `xhat`, you can notice that the solution flips and becomes negative. Is there a way to find the value of `xhat` at which this happens? Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

**Parameters:**

```
delta = 2/100;
epsilon = 3/2;
curlyphi = 5;
xi = 5/1000;
lambda = 1/2;
c = lambda*(epsilon - 1)*(1 + curlyphi);
theta = c + 0.05;
sigma = (20/100)^2;
muA = 5/100;
sigmaA = 10/100;
rn = delta + muA - sigmaA^2;
em = (delta*theta - Sqrt[delta^2*theta^2 + 4*theta*(epsilon - 1)*(1 + curlyphi)])/(2*theta);
ep = (delta*theta + Sqrt[delta^2*theta^2 + 4*theta*(epsilon - 1)*(1 + curlyphi)])/(2*theta);
a1 = (-delta*theta + Sqrt[delta^2*theta^2 + 4*theta*(epsilon - 1)*(1 + curlyphi)])/(2*theta);
a0 = -((xi + rn - 1/2*sigma - sigmaA*Sqrt[sigma])/(delta + a1))*a1;
a = (-delta*theta + Sqrt[delta^2*theta^2 + 4*lambda*(epsilon - 1)^2*(1 + curlyphi)^2])/(2*lambda*(epsilon - 1)*(1 + curlyphi));
xhat = -0.295;

System of Odes with boundary conditions:

OdeM = 1/2*sigma*Jx''[x] + ((delta*a0)/a1 - a1*x)*Jx'[x] - (epsilon - 1)/theta*(1 + curlyphi)*Jpi[x] - delta*Jx[x] == -2*x;
OdeP = 1/2*sigma*Jpi''[x] + ((delta*a0)/a1 - a1*x)*Jpi'[x] - Jx[x] == -2*lambda*(a0 + a1*x);
Ic1 = Jx[xhat] == 0;
Ic2 = Jx'[xhat] == 0;
Ic3 = Jpi[xhat] == (2*theta)/((epsilon - 1) (1 + curlyphi))*xhat;
Ic4 = Jpi'[xhat] == (2*theta)/((epsilon - 1) (1 + curlyphi));
```

**Solver:**

```
Sol = NDSolve[{OdeM, OdeP, Ic1, Ic2, Ic3, Ic4}, {Jx[x],Jpi[x]}, {x, -0.3, xhat}];
SolJx[x_] = Jx[x] /. Sol[[1]];
SolJpi[x_] = Jpi[x] /. Sol[[1]];
```

**Plot:**

```
Plot[SolJx[x], {x, -1, xhat}]
```

Comment: For `xhat = -0.520` `SolJx[x]`is pos. and neg.

Comment: How can you see that it is both positive and negative? I would like to figure out at what values of xhat Jx turns positive or negative. But I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Using TraditionalForm[OdeM] I see a trailing x on the left. Never seen a linear equation like that before. J''+anything linear in J =x yields an x^3 term,  not an element of a reasonable space of functions.

Comment: I don't understand this comment. Could you clarify? OdeM is one equation of a system of second order non-homogeneous differential equations. What is wrong with it?